Lebesgue Integration, Epsilon Boundedness of the Integral of Function f Implying f is 0 Almost Everywhere
I was working on the following question from the University of Hawaii Real Analysis PHD Qualifying Practice Exam:

$\text{Suppose } f \in L_1(\mathbb{R}) \text{ and there is } 0 < \varepsilon \text{ so that } \left| \int_A f(x) \, dx \right| \leq (m(A))^{1+\varepsilon} \text{ for all measurable sets } A \subseteq \mathbb{R}. \text{Prove that } f = 0 \text{ a.e.}$.

Thinking about the intuition for this problem, I understand that as $m(A)$ gets smaller, then the left integral must also get smaller. Therefore, if we take a sequence of sets that have decreasing positive measure, than the integral of $f$ on those sets must also be decreasing. However, I do not know why this implies that $f$ must be $0$ almost everywhere.
I tried to do a proof by contradiction. Suppose $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$ and there is $0 < \varepsilon$ so that $\left| \int_A f(x) \, dx \right| \leq (m(A))^{1+\varepsilon}$ for all measurable sets $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define the set $E_n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : |f(x)| > \frac{1}{n} \}$. Each set $E_n$ is measurable because $f$ is a measurable function. Given our assumption, we have $\left| \int_{E_n} f(x) \, dx \right| \leq (m(E_n))^{1 + \varepsilon}$. Since $|f(x)| > \frac{1}{n}$ for all $x \in E_n$, it follows that $\int_{E_n} |f(x)| \, dx > \int_{E_n} \frac{1}{n} \, dx = \frac{m(E_n)}{n}$. Therefore, $\frac{m(E_n)}{n} < (m(E_n))^{1 + \varepsilon}$. Then we are left with $1 < nm(E_n)^\epsilon$. However, this doesn't seem like a contradiction, because as $n$ goes to infinity, $m(E_n)$ also increases if we are assuming it is nonzero. Then, this inequality is very easily satisfied. I am not sure which other direction to go.

This is an easy consequence of Lebesgue's Differentiation Theorem. We have $\frac 1 {b-a} \int_a^{b} f(x)dx\leq (b-a)^{\epsilon} \to 0$ as $b \to a$ Hence $f(a)=0$ a.e..
Rf.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem
